# Every time to see changes I have to clear cache and refresh

Tags: javascript, webpack

*webpack.config.js*:

```
const path = require('path')
const config = require('config')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
    entry: './public/clientMain.js',
    node: { 
        fs: 'empty' 
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'app-v' + config.VERSION + '.js',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'start',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build/js')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/,
    },   
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          { from: 'public/assets', to: '../assets' }
        ])
    ]
}
```

in *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "concurrently \"node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -d --watch\" \"nodemon ./server/serverMain.js \" \"node ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -p 8080\""
```

},

The problem is Every time that I make a change in one of js files I have to clear Cache in browser and then refresh the page to see changes! (*Hard Reload* or ofc *Empty Cache and Hard Reload* in chrome)

I guess that is not normal? so How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do that is to add a hash to your output filename.

```
 output: {
        filename: 'app-v.[hash].' + config.VERSION + '.js',
    },
```